# How to create multiple files and their contents from a list?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in Python. I want to make some `.txt` files and their contents from this, but I see it only works on the first list (listA) which would be in the filename. And the items of it are all made. But the second list (listB) didn't work it only shows the last item ("3"). Please help me.

```py
listA = ["one", "two", "three"]
listB = ["1", "2", "3"]

for item in listA:
  for item2 in listB:
    with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "w") as f:
        f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
        f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(item2))
        f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```

Edit: I have tried changing the code,

```py
listA = ["one", "two", "three"]
listB = ["1", "2", "3"]

for item in listA:
    with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "a") as f:
        for item2 in listB:
            f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(item2))
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```

and this was the result in every file…

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 1 adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 2 adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 3 adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I was expecting that those placeholders should only appear once in every file orderly.

Edit: This is what I'm trying to make. For `randomone.txt`,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 1 adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

for `randomtwo.txt` is,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 2 adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

and so on…

Comment: Move the second `for` loop inside the `with` statement. You're overwriting your file leaving only the last modified version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the second for loop inside the with statement.

Your current code is overwriting your file for each item on listB leaving only the last modified version (i.e. item2 = "3").

```
for item in listA:
    with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "w") as f:
        for item2 in listB:
            f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(item2))
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```

You could also keep you current code and open the file in **append** mode (`'a'`), but this would be inefficient to close the file just to reopen it.

Edit: only repeat/update middle line

```
for item in listA:
    with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "w") as f:
        f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
        for item2 in listB:
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(item2))
        f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```

Edit 2: parallel looping over listA and listB

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for itemA, itemB in zip(listA, listB):
    with open("random{}.txt".format(itemA), "w") as f:
        f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
        f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(itemB))
        f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```

Comment: It worked but it repeats the line where the placeholder is located on every file 3 times. My only goal is to put orderly the items in listB for each file will be created.

Comment: @user17867382 why don't you provide the explicit expected output for one file?

Comment: on each file I should get 3 lines of text. for example if randomone.txt is created it should contain the number 1 on the middle line where the placeholder is located and so on in other files

Comment: @user17867382 I see, then you need to `zip`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the flag you are using. Right now you are using "w" flag to write to a file. This will overwrite the file if it already exist. If you use "a" (appending flag), it solves your problem. It appends to existing files and if the file does not exist it creates it.

```
with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "a") as f
```

Also, you can make your code more efficient by moving the inner loop inside the with statement. This way you only open the file once per each outer loop.

```
listA = ["one", "two", "three"]
listB = ["1", "2", "3"]

for item in listA:
    with open("random{}.txt".format(item), "w") as f:
        for item2 in listB:
            f.write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur {} adipiscing elit.".format(item2))
            f.write("\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
```